# co-registering a vector file to a georeferenced raster image

Tags: arcgis-desktop, envi

i would like to co-register a vector file to a raster image by a simple translation in envi.

Is it possible to do this in envi?

I have tried using the georeferencing tool in arcgis but the vector layer cannot be selected for georeferencing!

Answer (score 1):

In ArcGIS, the Georeferencing Tool is for Raster and CAD data. The Spatial Adjustment Tool is used for Vector data.

Comment: this has been helpful. i would also like to know if there is such a tool in envi.